# How to kill synergy/evict all connections

Tags: synergy

I install synergy on my ubuntu computer to use as server (kbd and mouse are plugged into it).  I install synergy on winPC to use as client.  Everything is great until I need to reboot winPC (as is so common with those win PC's).  Now synergy says

```
WARNING: failed to connect to server: server already has a connected client with our name.
```

If I quit synergy on the ubuntu machine and reopen it this error does not go away.  I have two solutions.  One: rename the windows computer and reboot it (unacceptable).  Two: Reboot ubuntu computer (completely unacceptable).

Why is synergy persisting a dead connection even after I close and reopen it?  `px ax | grep synergy` only returns the running grep.  How do I fix this without rebooting either computer?  Is synergy hiding under some other name, or does it leave files laying around I can delete?

Comment: Have you resolved your question?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'll play around with it more and try to accept an answer.  I've just been being real careful about trying not to reboot anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was having the same issue with server running on Fedora 16 and client on Windows 7. I finally found that the problem was that although I was stopping the client application from the PC toolbar there were actually client processes still running which were consequently keeping a connection open with the PC's name.

I killed in task manager restarted and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 1):

have you tried `ps -ef | grep synergy` instead

Comment: Doesn't list anything different.